# How to manually return observable without doing anything

Tags: angular, observable

I have a method that needs to check if a cookie is set, if the cookie is not set then it needs to make a http call to return the value for the cookie and then set it before I continue executing my code. That's all fine an dandy however if the cookie is set I don't need to make an http call I can just continue executing my code.

The problem is I don't know how to create a method that returns an observable without making a call to a native observable method like http.get.

```
private getAuthCookie(): Observable<any> {
  if (!this.hasCookie('oauth2')) {
    return this.http.get(address)
      .map((res: Response) => {
        this.setCookie('oauth2', res);
        return res
      }
  } else {
    return this.getCookie('oauth2');
    // complete the observable some how so that this.getAuthCookie().map() is a valid function
  }
}

private get(address: string, callback: any) {
  this.getAuthCookie()
    .map((token: Response) => {
      this.http.get(address, { headers: 'Bearer ' + token })
        .map(callback)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return Observable like:

```
private setAuthCookie(): Observable<any> {
  if (!this.hasAuthCookie()) {
    return this.http.get(address)
      .map((res: Response) => {
        this.setCookie('oauth2', res);
        return res
      }
  } else {
    return Observable.of<any>();
  }
}
```

Comment: This ought to be the accepted answer to the title of the question. Handy to, say, mock http calls during UI development.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move the check for the cookie existing outside of the method that way setAuthCookie() is doing only one thing and is only called when the cookie is not set.

Ex.

```
private getCookie(name: string) {
  if (!this.hasAuthCookie()) {
     var setCookie = setAuthCookie();
     //Do whatever you need to do with the returned observable
  } else {
    //Cookie exists, get cookie however you want
  }
}

private setAuthCookie(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(address)
      .map((res: Response) => {
        this.setCookie('oauth2', res);
        return res
      }
}
```

Comment: I had been leaning in this direction which cleaned up my code and improved testability.